# Date string from Excel into datetime variable

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I'm reading in an Excel file using pandas and putting the data into a dataframe.  I'm trying to take the date value in each row of the dataframe and convert it into a datetime object so I can change the formatting.  The dates in the dataframe are formatted like this: 2020-07-28 00:00:00.  My ultimate goal is to take the date in a different format and append it to a file name I'm then going to download from a website.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) package, and the [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) method. You can easily read deserialize a string into a python object. You specify the format with [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), which for you example would be `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`.

The excerpt below should give you the result you're looking for

```py
import datetime

datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-07-28 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: from dateutil.parser import parse
In [2]:  [parse(date).replace(tzinfo=None) for date in ['2020-09-11T22:44Z', '2020-09-11 22:44','11th september 2020 22h 44m']]
Out[22]:
[datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 11, 22, 44),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 11, 22, 44),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 11, 22, 44)]
```